# How to Use Range.Range Property

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Can someone tell me why this following use of the Range.Range property in Office 2010 Excel VSTO does not work? I have researched this a lot in Stackoverflow and other websites but can't figure it out.

```
currCol.Range[currCol.Cells[1, 1], currCol.Cells[500, 1]].Value2
```

where `currCol` is a `Range` object representing a column range in an Excel sheet. I just want to get the first 500 rows in the column.

The above expression returns a null value. I have also tried replacing `Value2` with `Value` but still no luck.

Comment: You don't say what you want as a result, or what "does not work" means. If you want to return a two-dimensional array with the 500 values, try: `ws.Range[currCol.Cells[1], currCol.Cells[500]]` where `ws` is a variable referring to the worksheet with the `currCol` range. You could also use: `currCol.Cells[1].Resize[500, 1]`

Comment: ws.Range[currCol.Cells[1], currCol.Cells[500]] did the trick! Thanks so much, Doug!